# Kendo Grid columnShow / Hide does not redistibute widths

Tags: javascript, dojo, telerik, grid, kendo-grid

My example illustrates my problem (with comments): http://dojo.telerik.com/eyIHi

Problem explained here again:

- I have a Kendo grid, the grid's width is dynamic (based on browser window width).
- The grid has 4 columns with width 50px only to illustrate the problem better! YET, the column widths are initially assigned differently so that they fill the grid's width!
- The first columns is hidden by default
- When running the example, the columns initially (even though only 50px) are spread out to use the complete width of the window (be sure to have a window size of more than 200px so that my sample works for you)
- After the grid has been initialized I run ***showColumn('ContactName')*** to unhide the first column
- Now because the columns combined width is less than the window width they should be spread out evenly again, but they are not.

Here is my code which is executed when the grid is built:

```
dataBound: function(e){
    e.sender.showColumn('ContactName');
},
```

I did not find a function to redistribute them like the grid does in the beginning (API here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid)

Answer (score 1):

Auto fitting all columns after the change, then removing the set width from the grid reimposes their ability to strech relatively!

http://dojo.telerik.com/UyEfa

```
for(i=0;i<=self.sender.columns.length;i++){
    self.sender.autoFitColumn(i);
}
self.sender.element.find('table[role="grid"]').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your columns to distribute evenly across the grid width, don't specify a width for any of them.  It does not sound like you want the columns to be 50px at all.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/aRUGi

Also, the Kendo documentation explains why your 50px columns stretch to fill the entire grid despite explicitly setting them the 50px: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#column-widths.  The paragraphs starting at "When all columns have pixel widths,..." is particularly relevent.

Comment: I want them to distribute relative to their width. BUT, when the total grid width is smaller than the total of column widths then the grid becomes scrollable (like a min-width)!